# How do I view an expression tree with LINQPad?

Tags: expression-trees, linqpad

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I how can I view the expression tree for this query:

```
from word in "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".Split()
orderby word.Length
select word
```

using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can view the objects that make up the expression tree as follows:

```
(from word in "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".Split().AsQueryable()
orderby word.Length
select word).Expression
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from word in "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".Split().AsQueryable()
orderby word.Length
select word
```

Then press the λ button next to Results.

EDIT: This will let you see the lambda expression, but I can't seem to find the expression tree in the sense of the [Expression Tree Visualizer](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2008/02/13/linq-farm-seed-using-the-expression-tree-visualizer.aspx). Allegedly LINQPad has (had?) one, but I'm not finding it either.

Comment: Yep, that's where I'm coming up short.  Thanks for the tip on the lambda, though--I couldn't get that working either.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `.Dump()` method available on all objects inside LinqPAD to dump an expression tree into the results window.